# ApplicationDbContext and AddScoped<IUnitOfWork,UnitOfWork> issue after scaffolding Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I can't run the project after scaffolding indentity

I believe it is not registering ApplicationDbContext properly when adding the service and so it complains in UnitOfWork when it requires an instance of the ApplicationDbContext.

Tried updating AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore and AspNetCore.EntityFrameworkCore, but this did not help

How do I fix this? I cannot proceed without it, thank you :)
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X97Q1.png)
[Installed packeges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTT8H.png)

ApplicationDbContext:

```
using BookHeaven.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BookHeaven.DataAccess;
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CoverType> CoverTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using BookHeaven.DataAccess;
using BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository;
using BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Customer}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

UnitOfWork.cs:

```
using BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository;
using BookHeaven.DataAccess;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            Category = new CategoryRepository(_db);
            CoverType = new CoverTypeRepository(_db);
            Product = new ProductRepository(_db);
        }
        public ICategoryRepository Category { get; private set; }
        public ICoverTypeRepository CoverType { get; private set; }
        public IProductRepository Product { get; private set; }
        public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Category Repository:

```
using BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using BookHeaven.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class CategoryRepository : Repository<Category>, ICategoryRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public CategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void Update(Category entity)
        {
            _db.Categories.Update(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        public ICategoryRepository Category { get; }
        public ICoverTypeRepository CoverType { get; }
        public IProductRepository Product { get; }

        void Save();
    }
}
```

Repository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory;

namespace BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            dbSet = _db.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string? includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var prop in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(prop);
                }
            }

            return query.ToList();
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity)
        {
            dbSet.RemoveRange(entity);
        }

        public T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression, string? includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
            query = query.Where(filterExpression);

            if(includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach(var prop in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(prop);
                }
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

**Full text error:**

> System.AggregateException HResult=0x80131500 Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'BookHeaven.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.) Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection StackTrace: at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build() at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\C#\ASP.NET\BookHeaven\BookHeavenWeb\Program.cs:line 21

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack: [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:

> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'BookHeaven.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.

Inner Exception 2:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BookHeaven.DataAccess.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'BookHeaven.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.

Comment: Can you please post full error text?

Comment: Can you share unitOfWork class with contructor ?

Comment: @firatt_ added UnitOfWork class

Comment: @NazarNyrka Maybe you can control your appSetting.json Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")

Comment: @firatt_
```{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=BookHeaven;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True",
    "ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=BookHeavenWeb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
``` 
here everything looks good

Comment: Maybe try => ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> or  ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>

Comment: @firatt_ Unfortunately, it didn't work, but I did notice one interesting thing. When I scaffold the identity in the Areas => Identity folder, a new Data folder is created with a new ApplicationDbContext.cs. Is this folder necessary?

Comment: Hi, how is your `IUnitOfWork` and `Repository<T>`? It works fine without error when run the application in my project.

Comment: @Rena No, I'm still trying to solve the problem

Comment: Hi @NazarNyrka, I mean it works fine in my project.....So pls share more code.

Comment: @Rena Can I send you the whole project?

Comment: Hi @NazarNyrka, I think you just need share the `IUnitOfWork` and `Repository<T>` part of code.

Comment: @Rena added to the topic